# How to insert a button inside jqGrid Cell?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to add a button inside a cell in jqGrid. The idea is to have that open a jQuery dialog and use that to upload file related to a certain record. And after the file is uploaded, we change the button with an image.

So basically, I need to know **how to insert custom Html into the jqGrid Cell**? I am using ASP .NET MVC 5. Any help/tips are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mean to insert "in every cell of the column" of the grid. [Custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) is the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question:

***how to insert custom Html into the jqGrid Cell?***

You can use custom formatter in colmodel definitions. you can target your colmodel cell where you want to show the button. You can use this:

```
formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowobject){
    return '<button type="button">Upload</button>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jai and @Oleg, you got me on the right track.

I know how to get the rowId from options parameter now but I need the primary key (which is available in the dataset and the Grid colModel) in the custom formatter. It seems to me that the rowId is an auto number.